# Not able to filter the categories component in the products page and not able to increment a certain product in the cart component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having difficulty in debugging these issues in my e-commerce app.

1. I am not able to filter the categories section, I don't know why.
2. In the cart component, you will eventually find the issue of increment of certain item.

So please can anyone take time to clone my github repo and solve this issue for me please.
Thanks in advance

https://github.com/Sourab054/Shoenique-ecommerce

[Click here for images regarding the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw9pE.png)

[Click here for images regarding the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaFQN.png)

Comment: Literally NO ONE will go through the stress of cloning and running your github project,  I'd advise you post the code sections that contain the code causing errors, screenshots are also welcome. Welcome to SO!

Comment: @web_walkerX I have included the images in the link, can you please go through it and give me a solution. It would be a great help to me

Comment: Please read through this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask